# Using Serial.begin() twice

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide

I'm training kids programming Arduino. We're gonna use `Serial` for debugging purposes, so we started with a simple HelloWorld program. I let them try various stuff, including changing the speed.

Now, one of the outcomes was as simple as

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("world");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("world");
}
```

My expectation was, that the Arduino does exactly as written, but the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE will become a bit consufed. When the monitor is set to 115200 baud, I expected to see

```
Hello
world
_#&%$"    < some garbage
world
_#&%$"    < garbage again
...
```

However, the real output is only one line

```
H⸮⸮⸮⸮C
```

Why is that? Is it impossible to change the baud rate in between?

The [official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial.Begin) does not say we can use `Serial.begin()` only once.

I'm using Arduino Uno and Arduino IDE 1.8.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the output of the serial is buffered. It's still sending the first bit of data while you change the baud rate - and from then on it's just a complete mess.

You need to force it to finish sending before you can change the baud rate by using `Serial.flush()`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello");
  Serial.flush();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("world");
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("world");
  Serial.flush();
}
```

That will wait after each print until all the data is sent out "onto the wire" before changing the baud rate for the next print.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Serial.end()` to reset the buffer pointer too?

Comment: Why? It's a circular buffer - there's no beginning or end to reset it to.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the read buffer. The OP is obviously a teacher. As he has to explain it to other people, he should be aware of what is also possible and what is the difference. Using `end()` will not only flush the write buffer, this also resets the read buffer. This can be important as the speed switch make only sense, if it is negotiated with the communication partner.  If this happens asynchronously, there might be unwanted data in the read buffer. On the other hand, there might be situations when the read buffer should be preserved, so using `end()`  can be a problem too.

Comment: BTW a circular buffer has head and tail pointers. Resetting the pointers in that case means set the head to the tail pointer to clear the buffer data.

Comment: You are assuming that is the case everywhere. That functionality is undocumented. Yes, the Arduino core does it, but there are no guarantees that every core does it. Or even every version of the Arduino core does it (for example flush changed from clearing the read buffer to blocking on the write buffer...). Plus disabling and re-enabling the serial port may cause unintended side effects (floating pins) which could cause problems.

Comment: The functionality is documented https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/end/ . Your last sentence makes me think. You are right, switching the pins back to common usage can cause problems too. This must be considered in the negotiation process. I think our conversation is very informative. ;-)  At least I have some new aspects to think about.

Comment: No the functionality "clear the rx buffer" is *not* documented.  The *function* is documented, with barely any information, but nowhere does it say anything about any buffers being cleared, or even `flush()` being performed.

Comment: I guess I would have implemented `Serial.begin()` in a way that `flush()` is built-in. But ok, ... I think the official documentation is not perfect yet.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: the good thing about teaching is: I always learn something new. Personally, I would never have written such a program, because it was clear to me that the output will be nonsense. But these kids (9 to 12 years) are not limited by their experience yet. They do funny random stuff, sometimes with unexpected outcome like this. And I hope there'll be more questions to be asked :-) I guess I can't explain it to them yet, because the concept of a "buffer" is way beyond their understanding.

Comment: I added a change request for the official documentation: https://github.com/arduino/reference-en/issues/711

Comment: @ThomasWeller I wish there were more like you. The documentation really needs a lot of work...

Comment: @ThomasWeller You are right, younger kids and artists are an unbelievable good source of inspiration. They don't fear about failures. They try things even if they think they wouldn't work.  I believe that is the difference between humans and computers and why computer can be creative. They are intended not to make errors. BTW: if the kids are really interested in MCU programming (for me it seems so) they learn with light speed. And questions about buffers can arise quicker than you think ;-)

Comment: Majenko I fully agree with you, that the documentation is in a worse state. I often have to look into the source code to find the information I am looking for. And the documentation is a nightmare for beginners. I often thought about contribute to the documentation after my investigations. But I fear my bad English is not understandable, especially for beginners. Because the documentation is not complete, I do not use it as a reference for my answers here.  "The code is the truth!"  Changes can happen in the code and also in the docs, so it doesn't matter where I based my answers on.